# Was this scarf in Once Upon A Time a reference to Doctor Who?

Tags: doctor-who, once-upon-a-time

In the episode "It's Not Easy Being Green" from *Once Upon A Time* there's a guy wearing this long, colorful scarf on the right, behind the Wicked Witch (who is trying to harness the power of ***time travel***):

[image]

[image]

Compare it with the fourth Doctor's famous scarf:

[image]

## Was the scarf a deliberate reference to Doctor Who?

Comment: I can't cite any production source (it's not actually a show I watch), but there's no way it was an **accidental** reference. Not with that scarf. You don't wear a scarf like that by accident :-D

Comment: I definitely agree with @MichaelScottShappe but don't have any proof too. But in Once  Upon A Time it wouldn't be the first reference at all. Actually, the plot is all about references to some known works.

Comment: Likewise I don't watch the show, but from what I know of it, and with how iconic the Tom Baker Dr Who scarf is, I can't see _any_ way it's anything but deliberate.